# Create a SQL Server/database backup via bicep?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-bicep

I have the following bicep to create a SQL Server and SQL Server database.

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-02-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlServerName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {}

  resource sqlDataBase 'databases@2021-02-01-preview' = {
    name: sqlServerName
    location: location
    sku: {
      name: 'GP_S_Gen5'
      tier: 'GeneralPurpose'
      family: 'Gen5'
      capacity: 4
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to create a SQL Server/database backup via bicep?

UPDATE:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases/backuplongtermretentionpolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

What each of these indicates: monthlyRetention, weeklyRetention, weekOfYear, yearlyRetention with some example

Comment: Are you trying to create a one off backup ? Otherwise you can configure backup policy using bicep

Comment: you can easily create backup retention policies

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases/backupshorttermretentionpolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases/backuplongtermretentionpolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: Can you please explain what each of these indicate: monthlyRetention, weeklyRetention, weekOfYear, yearlyRetention with some examples?

Comment: you probably wanna check the documentation around azure sql backups

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you **@Thomas** for your comments.

***I used below code from This [MS Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-bicep-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=CLI) and this [MS Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases/backuplongtermretentionpolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) to deploy Azure SQL Server with Backup:-***

> **main.bicep:-**
>
> ```json
> param  serverName  string = uniqueString('sql', resourceGroup().id)
>
>   
>
> @description('The name of the SQL Database.')
>
> param  sqlDBName  string = 'SampleDB'
>
>   
>
> @description('Location for all resources.')
>
> param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
>
>   
>
> @description('The administrator username of the SQL logical server.')
>
> param  administratorLogin  string
>
>   
>
> @description('The administrator password of the SQL logical server.')
>
> @secure()
>
> param  administratorLoginPassword  string
>
>   
>
> resource  sqlServer  'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
>
> name: serverName
>
> location: location
>
> properties: {
>
> administratorLogin: administratorLogin
>
> administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
>
> }
>
> }
>
>   
>
> resource  sqlDB  'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview'
> = {
>
> parent: sqlServer
>
> name: sqlDBName
>
> location: location
>
> sku: {
>
> name: 'Standard'
>
> tier: 'Standard'
>
> }
>
> }
>
>   
>
> resource  backupPolicy 
> 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies@2022-05-01-preview'
> = {
>
> parent: sqlDB
>
> name: 'default'
>
> properties: {
>
> monthlyRetention: 'P1M'
>
> weeklyRetention: 'P1W'
>
> weekOfYear: 1
>
> yearlyRetention: 'P1Y'
>
> }
>
> }
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

> What each of these indicates: monthlyRetention, weeklyRetention, weekOfYear, yearlyRetention with some example

LTR- Is a long term retention or long term storage of your Azure DB backup in Azure blob storage.

PTIR- Is a point in time restore, Which refers to the backup taken at a particular time and you can use the same backup later when your data is lost. You can configure how much days you want to keep your PTIR copy by creating a policy above where the PTIR is set to 7 Days.

The above Bicep code sets Point in time restore days to 7, Which means you can restore your PTIR backups within 7 days.
And how frequently I want to take a backup is set by Differential backup frequency which is set to 24 hours.

PTIR Reference is the same [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql#backup-usage) shared by @Thomas in comments.

> Now, Coming to LTR that is Long term retention policy - Weekly LTR is  keeping the LTR backup to storage for a week which is set to 1 week.
> Monthly LTR is keeping the LTR backup  to storage for a month which is set to 1.
> And Yearly LTR is keeping an LTR backup to storage for a year which is set to 1st week of 1 year. If you want to understand LTR in more detail, Refer this [MS Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-retention-overview?view=azuresql#how-long-term-retention-works)

Comment: Thank you! If I have two databases within the server, can I have backup set for one database.

Comment: Yes, You can just add that sqlDB resource in parent like here - parent: sqlDB

name: 'default'

properties: {

monthlyRetention: 'P1M'